# How to setup Nightwatch.js with Symfony and VueJS?

Tags: symfony, vue.js, symfony4, e2e-testing, nightwatch.js

I use Symfony 4 together with VueJS. In `src/Controller` I have `HomeController.php` which renders `templates/home/index.html.twig`. Inside this template I call the VueJS application:

```
{% extends 'base.html.twig' %}

{% block title %}My App{% endblock %}

{% block stylesheets %}
    {{  encore_entry_link_tags('spa') }}
{% endblock %}

{% block body %}
  <div id="app">
  </div>
{% endblock %}

{% block javascripts %}
  {{  encore_entry_script_tags('spa') }}
{% endblock %}
```

In the root directory I have a subdirectory `assets`:

```
- css
- js
- spa
```

The VueJS application lives inside `spa`. The directories `css` and `js` contain stylesheets and scripts used by other parts of the Symfony app (Admin).

How do I setup Nightwatch.js to run end to end tests?

I created this under `spa`:

```
- main.js
- App.vue
- components
- router
- store
- tests
  - e2e
    - nightwatch.conf.js
    - reports
    - specs
```

The `nightwatch.conf.js` looks like this:

```
module.exports = {
  src_folders: ['assets/spa/tests/e2e/specs'],
  output_folder: 'assets/spa/tests/e2e/reports',
  selenium: {
    start_process: true,
    server_path: require('selenium-server').path,
    host: '127.0.0.1',
    port: 4444,
    cli_args: {
      'WebDriver.chrome.driver': require('chromedriver').path
    }
  },
  test_settings: {
    chrome: {
      desiredCapabilities: {
        browserName: 'chrome'
      }
    }
  }
};
```

As far as I understand first I should start the server. But since the Twig template is served by Symfony I should start:

```
symfony server:start
```

and then run `yarn test:e2e` where `test:e2e` is this line inside `package.json`:

```
"test:e2e": "nightwatch --config assets/spa/tests/e2e/nightwatch.conf.js --env chrome"
```

I have set up a simple sanity test inside `assets/spa/tests/e2e/specs/`:

**`journeys.js`**

```
module.exports = {
  'sanity_test': function(browser) {
    browser
      .url('http://localhost:8000')
      .waitForElementVisible('div.body', 2000)
      .end();
  }
};
```

but when I run `yarn test:e2e` I get the following error:

> TypeError: Error while trying to create HTTP request for
>   "/wd/hub/session/30561d2683d7c3c049fc1a993f7840e5/element/[object
>   Object]/displayed": Request path contains unescaped characters

Answer (score 0):

It seems this change:

```
test_settings: {
    chrome: {
      desiredCapabilities: {
        browserName: 'chrome',
        chromeOptions: {
          w3c: false
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

has solved the problem and the test is now passing. I feel little bit stupid after writing this long question and finding a solution after few minutes.

Maybe someone can add something valuable and give more detailed explanation or share best practices.